# How to determinate if a non-existing file is a directory?

Tags: java, file

File.isDirectory() "returns true if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; false otherwise"

Hovewer I need to know if the file is a directory BEFORE I create it.

How to?

Comment: Err, by calling isDirectory()? If it doesn't exist, it's not a directory, since it doesn't even exist.

Comment: How can an abstract path be a directory _before_ you create it?! It doesn't exist, therefore it is neither a file nor a directory.

Comment: Schrödinger's iNode?

Comment: An object that does not exist is neither a file not a directory because, well, it does not exist.

Comment: Try to create the directory then, if this fails, try to find the reason it fails. It can fail for multiple reasons (f.e. insufficient permissions) even if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java File represents either file or directory. You don't know what it is when it doesn't exist. When you have:

```
 File newFile = new File("C:\\name");
```

You can create either directory:

```
 newFile.mkdir();
```

OR file:

```
 newFile.createNewFile();
```